# Taking an Array of any size as an argument of a function with generics

Tags: arrays, go, generics

## Previously

it wasn't possible to take an array of any size as an argument of a function in golang, you had to use slices, which is highlighted by many stack overflow answers.

## Now

with the recent introduction of generics is it possible to take an array of any size as an argument? I tried my best but it doesn't seem to work :(

## My attempt

```golang
func foo[A [N]V, V comparable, N int](array A) {
    fmt.Println(array)
}
```

## Error

```golang
./prog.go:9:13: invalid array length N
./prog.go:15:5: cannot infer V (prog.go:9:18)
```

Comment: Note that the [`ArrayLength` of an array type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Array_types) is _not itself a type_. _It is an expression that MUST evaluate to a __constant__ representable by a non-negative `int`._ The `N` in your example is a type parameter, not an int expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> with the recent introduction of generics is it possible to take an array of any size as an argument?

No. Use a slice.